# Can parse JSON using the json package in GHCI but not when compiled with GHC

Tags: json, haskell

I'm trying to parse a JSON string using the json library. This code works perfectly in GHCI:

```
import Text.JSON as JS
JS.decode  "{}"  :: Result JSValue
```

But when I use the same code in a compiled program:

```
case JS.decode "{}" of
  JS.Ok value -> putStrLn value
  JS.Error err -> error err
```

It is unable to parse the String with:

```
Unable to read String
```

I suspect it's just me doing something stupid but I can't figure out what....

Any ideas very very welcome!

**Update:**

I wrote this code to see if it was something in the other part of the app causing the problem:

```
import qualified Text.JSON as JS

main :: IO ()
main = do
   case JS.decode "{}" of
                JS.Ok value -> putStrLn value
                JS.Error err -> error err
```

However I get the same error with this:

```
test: Unable to read String
```

It's compiled with GHC 7.0.3 and the source was edited with vim. However even string data passed in from outside the app generate the same error. Really out of ideas now...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `print` instead of `putStrLn`, which only works on Strings:

```
import qualified Text.JSON as JS

main :: IO ()
main = do
   case JS.decode "{}" of
            JS.Ok value -> print (value :: JSValue)
            JS.Error err -> error err
```

Answer (score 2):

I think this is just a capitalization issue with `JS.Decode` instead of `JS.decode`.  The following works fine for me with the latest Haskell platform.

```
module Foo where
import qualified Text.JSON as JS

foo :: IO ()
foo = case JS.decode "{}" of
   JS.Ok value -> putStrLn value
   JS.Error err -> error err
```

Comment: Oops, that was a typo. In the actual code it is lower case, but you've given me an idea :)

Comment: If it was actually a capitalization issue, he would have gotten a different error. Still, well spotted.